# How can I utilize OOP with this basic calculation script?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to write a simple calculator to calculate how fast my battery will drain from 100% to 0% by taking a time and percentage for start and subtracting it from the finish time and percentage.

I was able to make a quick and dirty script to accomplish this, but I am learning OOP, and I would like some feedback on how to improve my code and implement OOP for this task. I added in some verbose print statements to make it easier for me to remember what everything is when I run it, and I intend to wrap it up into a simple bash script or maybe implement tkinter for GUI.

Any thoughts or suggestions will help! My main environment is python 3, but I added the error handling for those who run with python2 because it doesn't like a preceding 0 in the time number.

```
from datetime import timedelta

# Getting inputs for time and percentage

try:
    start_time = str(input('What is the starting time in 24 hour time? Format: HHMM >> '))
    start_time_hr = start_time[:2]
    start_time_min = start_time[2:]
except SyntaxError:
    print('Try entering the time again without the preceding 0. \n')
    start_time = str(input('What is the starting time in 24 hour time? Format: HHMM >> '))
    start_time_hr = start_time[0]
    start_time_min = start_time[1:]

start_perc = int(input('What is the starting battery percentage? >> '))

try:
    end_time = str(input('What is the finish time in 24 hour time? Format: HHMM >> '))
    end_time_hr = end_time[:2]
    end_time_min = end_time[2:]
except SyntaxError:
    print('Try entering the time again without the preceding 0. \n')
    end_time = str(input('What is the finish time in 24 hour time? Format: HHMM >> '))
    end_time_hr = end_time[0]
    end_time_min = end_time[1:]

end_perc = int(input('What is the ending battery percentage? >> '))

# Turning numbers into times for calculation

start = timedelta(hours=int(start_time_hr), minutes=int(start_time_min))
end = timedelta(hours=int(end_time_hr), minutes=int(end_time_min))

# Calculating and printing the results

perc_difference = float(-(end_perc - start_perc))
time_difference = end - start
time_difference_minute = time_difference.total_seconds() / 60
discharge = (100.0 * time_difference_minute / perc_difference) / 60

print()
print()
print('*****')
print('Percentage Difference = ' + str(perc_difference))
print('Minutes Passed = ' + str(time_difference.total_seconds() / 60))
print('100% to 0% in ~' + str(round(discharge, 2)) + ' hours.')
print('*****')
print()
print()
print()
```

Comment: Requests to improve working code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, not every task benefits from OOP. Also, nothing you are doing in this script will raise a `SyntaxError` that you can catch at run time in Python 3, and if you are using Python 2, you should be using `raw_input`, not `input`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this program will benefit from using OOP.

That said; I do have a few notes on style and lack of defensive programming.

First; You do not need to wrap an `input` call with `str`, since it returns a string by default.

Second; You have wrapped a couple of your `input` calls with `int`, which is perfectly fine, but these need to be wrapped in `try` blocks as any input that cannot be converted to an integer will raise a `ValueError`.

Third; You should NEVER be handling a syntax error in that way. If you're getting syntax errors, fix the code, don't try to wrap it with a bandaid.

Fourth; You do not need to write that many `print` statements.

The entire print block could be rewritten as follows:

```
print('*****\nPercentage Difference = ' + str(perc_difference) + 'Minutes Passed = ' + str(time_difference.total_seconds() / 60)) + "\n100% to 0% in ~' + str(round(discharge, 2)) + ' hours.\n' +
*****')
```

Or, in my opinion; the much more readable [fstring](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) variant:

```
msg = f"*****\nPercentage Difference = {perc_difference}\nMinutes Passed = {time_difference.total_seconds() / 60}\n100% to 0% in ~{round(discharge,2)} hours.\n"

print( msg )
```